# Vertical slider for chrome and moz

Tags: html, css, slider

Im styling a vertical slider using -moz and -webkit.
With mozilla i declare it vertical using orient="vertical" and all the styling works fine.
With chrome since im using -webkit-appearance: none; for styling i can't use -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical, this forces me to use -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

The issue is that in mozilla i can use height to declare the real height of the slider instead by rotating it with chrome i'm forced to use width.

```
#sens[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
     height: 220px; //in chrome is width since it is rotated
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: why you can't use -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical ?

Comment: because then you cannot add custom styles to it. see: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341071

Answer (score 3):

ok, I think you need something like this.

For first you need to read about `::-webkit-slider-runnable-track` and `::webkit-slider-thumb`. [link1](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-runnable-track) and [link2](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-thumb) very useful properties.

And now you can do that like that:

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: 50px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

Comment: Am i wrong or the vertical slider is horizontal in your code? That is not what i've asked

Comment: @user217354 You see in code horizontal slider? What browser you are using?

Comment: With firefox it's horizontal, with chrome it's vertical. The slider must be vertical in all browsers

Comment: @user217354 oh, you're right) I've updated answer. Just remove ` orient="vertical"`